# Subreporte no itera en ireport

Tags: ireport

tengo un reporte diseñado en ireport el cual usa un subreporte para el detalle, el problema que tengo es que solo me despliega el primer registro, es decir, no itera.
La fuente de datos es una clase data source que le paso al informe principal desde un programa java, ya me aseguré que llegan todos los registros...debo indicarle al subreporte que debe iterar?

Comment: Cuál reporte? Cuál subreporte? Cuál fuente de datos? Cuál programa java? Cómo te aseguraste de tener todos los registros? En algún lugar debes iterar sobre los registros, sea llamando N veces el subreporte o iterando dentro ¿no? Como ves, esta pregunta es hasta ahora un ejercicio de adivinación. Si quieres, puedes [edit] y convertirla en una pregunta concreta con un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (incluso si termina cerrada, una buena pregunta siempre es reabierta y recibe respuestas)